# How do I fix sonarqube guava version incompatibility (closeQuietly) in my project?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When I compile and test my custom sonarqube plugin locally, it works fine, but when running an analysis on the server, the build fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:220)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:175)
at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:56)
at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:112)
at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:136)
at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:129)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:90)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
... 32 more
```

Running a `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` gives me all the usages of guava, where:

- `org.sonarsource.sslr:sslr-testing-harness:1.21` needs `10.0.1`
- `org.sonarsource.java:sonar-java-plugin:4.2` needs `19.0`
- `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2` needs `18.0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

### Solution #1

Work around the problem by downgrading guava in your project like so:

```xml
...

<dependencies>

    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.sonar.java}</version>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>

...
```

**NOTE:** The exclusion on the `sonar-plugin-java` entry is a little overkill, but I always prefer to be careful with transients. Also, the guava library can probably be marked as provided, but I haven't tested that.

### Solution #2

The sslr plugin appears to be the cause of it, and since migrating to java 7 its had try-with-resources to replace `Closeables#closeQuietly`.

There is an open pull-request to remove the guava dependency: https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr/pull/1

Vote on that and get the SonarSource devs to implement a fix.

*I know it's not much of a solution, but hopefully enough people will upvote the request so they'll do something about it. In the mean-time, option 1 is a perfectly valid workaround.*

#### Related discussions:

- http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Problem-with-conflicting-Guava-versions-td5033244.html
- https://marc.info/?l=sonar-dev&m=142651630903693&w=2
- [Custom plugin for SonarQube 5.2 produces NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369058/custom-plugin-for-sonarqube-5-2-produces-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: I think the solution 1 can be simplified. Could you please attach all your dependencies ?